# How do you prevent continuously looping #include statements?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem with two classes that each need to know about the other in their header file.

#### Structure.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H
#define STRUCTURE_H

#include <vector>
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Bullet.h"

class Structure: public Sprite{
public:
Structure(const BITMAP bm, const Vec2& pos, const Vec2& vel,
              const RECT boundaries, std::vector<std::vector<bool>> holes);
virtual ~Structure() = 0;

void takeDamage(const Bullet* bullet);
protected:
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> mBulletHoles;
};

#endif
```

#### Structure.cpp

```
#include "Structure.h"

Structure::Structure(const BITMAP bm, const Vec2& pos, const Vec2& vel,
                     const RECT boundaries, std::vector<std::vector<bool>> holes)
    :Sprite(bm, pos, vel, boundaries),
     mBulletHoles(holes)
{}

void Structure::takeDamage(const Bullet* bullet){

}

Sprite::~Sprite(){}
```

#### Bullet.h

```
#ifndef BULLET_H
#define BULLET_H

#include "Animate.h"
#include "Structure.h"

class Bullet: public Sprite{
public:
Bullet(const BITMAP bm, const Vec2& pos, const Vec2& vel, const RECT boundaries, 
           bool friendly);
virtual ~Bullet();

int checkCollision(Animate* target);
void checkCollision(Structure* target, float dt);

private:
float mTimeSinceCollision;

bool mFriendly;
bool mActive;

const static float mPenetrationTime;
};

#endif
```

#### Bullet.cpp

```
#include "Bullet.h"

Bullet::Bullet(const BITMAP bm, const Vec2& pos, const Vec2& vel,
               const RECT boundaries, bool friendly)
:Sprite(bm, pos, vel, boundaries),
 mTimeSinceCollision(0.0f),
 mFriendly(friendly),
 mActive(true)
{}

int Bullet::checkCollision(Animate* target){
int returnPoints = 0;
if((target->identifier() == "Player") && !mFriendly){
    if(isTouching(target)){
        target->takeDamage();
        mActive = false;
    }
}else if((target->identifier() == "Alien") && mFriendly){
    if(isTouching(target)){
        returnPoints = target->takeDamage();
        mActive = false;
    }
}
return returnPoints;
}

void Bullet::checkCollision(Structure* target, float dt){
if(isTouching(target)){
    mTimeSinceCollision += dt;
    target->takeDamage(this);
}
if(mTimeSinceCollision >= mPenetrationTime){
    mActive = false;
}
}

Bullet::~Bullet(){}

const float Bullet::mPenetrationTime = .05;
```

because the two header files call each other, I am getting many errors. I tired replacing

```
#include "Bullet.h"
```

in Structure.h with

```
class Bullet;
```

but then the compiler said I had multiply defined types. How are you supposed to get around the looping #include statements?

Comment: What you did should have worked, as long as you also include `Bullet.h` from `Structure.cpp`. What exactly was the compiler error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers Including Each Other in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c)

Comment: Unfortunately: `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization that is inefficient (it is optimized for space). If speed is critical you may want to try `std::vector<char>` but don't forget to test to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

First, you want to avoid those circular include. Then, if really there is no way out, you simply declare the class you need in the header.

For instance, in the Bullet.h :

```
#include "Sprite.h"

class Structure; // Can now use Structure* and Structure&
class Bullet {
...
}
```

In Bullet.cpp

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Structure.h"
```

In the Structure.h :

```
#include "Sprite.h"

class Bullet;   // Can now use Bullet* and Bullet&
class Structure {
...
}
```

In Structure.cpp

```
#include "Structure.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
```

When the compiler will see the unknown "Sprite" object in the Bullet implementation, he'll know you're referring to a particular object, since you declared in the header. See in the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11) for instance.

Comment: There is always a way out. Because in C++ you can't have circular dependency its not possible.

Comment: I don't think one should necessarily avoid these in all cases -- If `b.h` needs `a.h`, and `c.h` needs parts in `a.h` and `b.h`, `c.h` should `#include` both headers. You don't want `c.h` to break if someone comes along and removes `b.h`'s dependency on `a.h`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you're including the headers within each other.  I.e you're including structure in bullet and vice versa, which is causing a multiple inclusion error.  The inclusion guards you have up top prevent this, but I still find it happens in some cases, this being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In a header file, if you do not have anything other than pointers to that class (members and/or parameters / return types), you can use the forward declaration instead of including the header:

```
class Bullet;
```

You still need to include both Structure.h and Bullet.h in the cpp file, because it needs the full definition for both.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to the class instead of the class in one of the files and allocate it through `new` (and `delete` it in the dtor, ofc).

The thing is, the size of a pointer is ALWAYS known to the compiler, so it won't complain and compile your code. This is called **forward declaration**. It's very well documented.

Answer (score -1):

adding **#pragma once** would help, but having a better include structure to avoid loops would be good too.

**#pragma once** makes sure the current file is included only once in a single compilation, for more info on #pragma once visit 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once