# Mysterious compiler errors with C++ header files referencing each other

Tags: c++, visual-c++

OK, this is stumping me. Relative C++ noob, but long experience with C# and other languages.

Here's a relatively simple distillation of the problem files:

```
/* GameObject.h */
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class GameObject {
    public:
    std::vector<Component *> *Components;
    GameObject();
    ~GameObject();
};


/* GameObject.cpp */
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Component.h"
GameObject::GameObject() {
}

GameObject::~GameObject() {
}


/* Component.h */
#pragma once
class Component {
    public:
    GameObject *Owner;
    Component();
    ~Component();
};


/* Component.cpp */
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Component.h"
Component::Component() {
}
Component::~Component() {
}
```

This generates 21 totally irrelevant errors in Visual C++ 2012, I guess stemming from the fact that it couldn't compile Component:

```
C2065: 'Component' : undeclared identifier  gameobject.h    10
C2059: syntax error : '>'   gameobject.h    10
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    gameobject.h    14
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'    component.h 3
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    component.h 11
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'    gameobject.cpp  8
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    gameobject.cpp  9
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'    gameobject.cpp  13
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    gameobject.cpp  14
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    gameobject.cpp  16
C1004: unexpected end-of-file found gameobject.cpp  16
C2065: 'Component' : undeclared identifier  gameobject.h    10
C2059: syntax error : '>'   gameobject.h    10
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    gameobject.h    14
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'    component.h 3
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    component.h 11
C2653: 'Component' : is not a class or namespace name   component.cpp   8
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'    component.cpp   8
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'    component.cpp   9
C2653: 'Component' : is not a class or namespace name   component.cpp   13
C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   component.cpp   13
```

Any ideas? It makes sense in the design for Component to have a pointer to GameObject, and GameObject to have a vector of pointers to Components, so I'm not about to rearchitect to avoid that. I'm guessing I'm just doing something wrong with the header files.

Thanks in advance for any ideas, this one's driving me crazy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headers Including Each Other in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to fix this is to add  forward declarations - Component before GameObject definition and vice versa

```
class GameObject;
class Component {
...
```

and

```
class Component;
class GameObject{
...
```

Technically you just need the 2nd one because of the way you order your .h files. But it is better you add both.

The **reason** for this is because if we think of your `.h` as independant C++ files, by the time we(the compiler) come across the definition of the vector of `Component` pointers (why is this a pointer to a vector??), we still have no idea what `Component` is. It could be a class, a function, a typo, anything. This is why you need a forward declaration to let the compiler know to assume it is a class.

This would work only in the  case of pointers/references to other classes. If it were a vector of `Component` objects, you would have had no choice but to include the  header before the definition.

Comment: Cool - so that was the trick, a forward declaration of " class GameObject; " above the Component class definition and vise-versa. Thanks. Header files suck :)

Comment: Better yet, just combine the two header files. Each is just part of the description of one concept.

Comment: The classes will be getting a lot more complex over time, so I want to maintain one file per class if I can.

Comment: @QuadrupleA you're right, combining them in one header is bad advice.

Comment: My "bad advice" is because the files must always and everywhere be used together. So put them together. A future developer, after some digging around, discovers that GameObject.h is needed. He includes it, but his project still will not compile. Something else is needed. Back to digging. In more complex cases, it can get worse than that. A rule that I have used since the 80's is that every header file must #include every header that it depends on. Works good. Saves much grief.

Comment: @Karthik_T: Re: the pointer to vector, was thinking it'd give me more control over allocation / deletion, and prevent problems with GameObjects growing as vectors grow - but now that you mention it, having it as a direct member makes more sense. Vector uses a pointer internally anyway, so I guess it would allocate outside the object regardless.

Comment: @QuadrupleA yes pointer to vector makes little sense from allocation standpoint. In fact if all Components are uniquely owned by one GameObject, I would recommend  vector of objects, to simplify your code. It would still be allocated on the heap by the vector. This would require more than just a forward declaration, however, as I have mentioned.

Comment: @Karthik: Interesting - so "std::vector<Component> Components;" rather than "std::vector<Component *> Components;" ?

Comment: @QuadrupleA, Yes that might make things easier/neater. One thing to check is if your Component needs a copy constructor, esp if your are using a pre c++11 compiler

Comment: Hmm - would probably run into trouble, as Component will actually be a base class of hundreds of derived classes (SpriteComponent, RedBeetleBehaviorComponent, etc.). So would probably need the pointers for polymorphism.

Comment: @QuadrupleA ah yes, I should have thought of that. In that case I would recommend [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for the vector. And [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) for Owner ptr, if you are using a c++11 compiler, otherwise you can leave things as they stand.

Comment: @KarthikT: Cool, will check those out.

Answer (score 1):

Put a forward declaration of Component at the top, after #pragma once, like so...

```
class Component; // Just this, no more.
```

There might still be errors, but that's a start.

I recommend that you combine GameObject.h and Component.h into one file. They are closely linked, so they belong together.

Comment: Thanks - looks like forward declarations for classes are the key. I do want to keep a one-file-pair-per-class structure though.  I thought the .h file class defintions WERE forward declarations, but I guess that's just true of methods, not of the class itself. Confusing.

Comment: You can keep them separate and it will still work. Just put the forward declaration at the top of GameObject.h. Putting them together eliminates a dependency. I do not know why you would want to separate them, but do as you will.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oops. I have only been programming in C++ since 1984. One of these days I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: May I ask the motivation for the downvote on Karthik's answer?

Comment: They're both upvotes in my book. But I have less than 15 comments still :). So not allowed.

Comment: Don't think it was me, unless I clicked accidentally or something. When I upvote it says "Upvote requires 15 reputation" and disallows it. I marked Karthik's as the accepted answer.

Comment: @QuadrupleA oh I'm sorry, I was talking to Jive. :) You're good!