# class reference to istelf

Tags: c++, class, recursion, reference

I have a class which is becoming too large and should be split up. However the classes it is to be split up into ideally need access to the variables of the main class. I am trying to make a template class which has a reference to the main class, but I seem to have the problem of include recursion. I have searched and people say that you can use forward declarations, but I still get the error of incomplete type. I know this is a common question and I have seen the thread [Headers Including Each Other in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c) , but none of the answers seem to make sense or work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

classmain.h

```
class classref;
class classmain
{
public:
    classmain()
:B(*this)
{};

 classref B;
 int a;
};
```

classref.h

```
#include "classmain.h"

class classref
{
public:
classref(classmain& ref)
    :A(ref)
{};

 classmain& A;
};
```

Comment: You are creating a circular dependency which you must ressolve...

Comment: You have your forward declaration and include reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you declare `classmain::B` to be an instance of the `classref` class. Then it needs the *complete* definition of `classref`.

I would suggest you actually declare `classmain` in the `classref.h` file instead, and include `classref.h` in `classmain.h`. So the opposite of what you do now in regards of declarations and inclusions.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. That works, but I can't access member variables of classmain from within classref now?

Comment: You can if you put the implementation of `classmain` in a source file which includes the 2 headers.