# Declaring a pointer to a class object within a class declaraion

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not a C++ guy, so some simple things still trip me up.  I am using Qt and trying to get my Qt project done (it will be used to test a TCP/IP connection I am installing on a proto board).

In my mainwindow class, I want to include pointers to the client & server objects that get created when you push a button on the main window form.  But when I put that declaration in the class, it doesn't appear as though the class knows what it is, even though I have included the header file.

Here's a snippet of my mainwindow class:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    EchoServer *mServer;
    EchoClient *mClient;
...
```

The EchoServer & Client lines get a syntax error and then missing type specifiers.

But when I put that same declaration in the mainwindow.cpp file in the button push event, there's no error!?  Here a snippet of that function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
    const ushort port = 9999;
    EchoServer *mServer;

    EchoServer server((const QString)ui->lineEdit_IP_Addr->text(), port, ui );
    EchoClient client((const QString)ui->lineEdit_IP_Addr->text(), port, ui );
    ...
```

Any idea, what am I missing?

Comment: you should include headers where you define your EchoServer and EchoClient classes in your mainwindow header file ... or you can forward declare your EchoServer and EchoClient classes, because you use pointer to them

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the forward declaration in your header file like:

```
class EchoServer;
class EchoClient;

class MyClass
{

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    EchoServer *mServer;
    EchoClient *mClient;
};
```

Comment: Thanks vahancho!  That worked....I figured it had to be something simple, yet I guess I still don't understand why I need that!?  I included the header file that defines those classes in this header file.  What does the forward declaration do that my header file does not?  Joe B.

Comment: @JoeB., actually you could use both approaches equally. However if it is a matter of declaring pointers, better to use the forward declaration, because compiler just need to know that you use the correct names. One if the benefits of doing so is decreasing the compilation time.

Comment: @JoeB. You didn't happen to include `mainwindow.h` in one of those two headers? Because what you explained is a symptom of [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c) can help you understand this a little better.