# Mutual Import C++

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

I know this is a reoccurring question, but so far I have basically only seen the answer “if you have mutual imports you are doing something wrong”.

That is why I have more of a general understanding question than one tied to some specific code.

Okay, so as an example. Say I have a data structure for a dynamic automaton. The states of the automaton are structs with an attribute “transitions”. “transitions” is a dynamic linked list. The list elements are structs that have as an attribute a State object...

So:

```
// state.h
#include "transitionList.h"

State{
    TransitionList transitions; // all transitions going out from this state
}

// tranistion.h
#include "state.h"

Transition{
    Transition* next_transition; // the next transition in the TransitionList
    State* successor; // a pointer to the next state in the automaton
}


// transitionList.h
#include "tranisiton.h"

TransitionList{
    // *code* class for a linked list of transitions
}
```

So we have state.h -> tranistion.h -> transitionList.h -> state.h -> …

This is obviously circular... but where is the conceptual mistake? I don't see how this is a bad layout from a formal point of view.

Please enlighten me :)

Comment: That isn't valid C++ code.

Comment: Yea, it was supposed to be more pseudo code than anything.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually it's fine. It's just physically not going to work because C++ doesn't have a physical module system. The `#include` directive just inserts a copy of the included file, so circular includes will produce a source stream of infinite length.

You need to present the compiler with the classes in a certain order that it can compile, the combination being known as a "translation unit".

Where you have a class that holds a pointer to another class that has not yet been fully declared, you have to "forward declare" it:

```
class State;
```

That trick allows one of the class headers to not need to include the full definition of something that it holds a pointer to, and breaks the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought that would only work if the two classes shared the same file.

But does this alone prevent nested importing? Or do I still need the #ifndef logic?

Comment: It's good practise to wrap the header in pre-processor guff to make it safe for multiple inclusion, because otherwise your future client code has to be careful about the order in which it includes things. It's a good idea to have a single `.cpp` file for each `.h` file, such that the `.cpp` file's very first line includes the `.h` file (even if that's all it contains), as this proves that the `.h` file can be included first, and so this tests the independent "includeability" of every header.

Comment: Also note that (because C++ has no physical module system) the boundaries between source files are not significant to the language. The pre-processor joins files together (via `#include`) into a single stream and the compiler doesn't care where the source came from.

Comment: Thank you. Will have to chew on that for a bit.