# How should I arrange header files of two classes and avoid incomplete type if they have to include each other?

Tags: c++

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_
class A;
#include "B.h"
class A{
public : 
    A(const B &b) : bitem(b.data) {}
    A() {}
private:
    int bitem = 0;
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_
#include "A.h"
class B{
friend class A;
public:
    B() {}
A func(){
    A aitem;
    return aitem;
}
private:
    int data = 0;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it,I get error:

> error: return type ‘class A’ is incomplete

But if I remove the foward declaration of class A in A.h,I will get error like this:

> error: ‘A’ does not name a type

How can I arrange A and B ? Is there any circular definition ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headers Including Each Other in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declare B in A.h

```
class B;
```

Remove the include #include "B.h"

Remove the definition of the constructor from the header and move it into A.cpp. Add the include of B.h in the Cpp.

Of course you will also have to link, main and A modules together. If you are using an IDE you shouldn't have to worry about it, but if you aren't you'll need to look it up for your toolchain if you don't know how.