# Return one class in the function of the other class and vise versa, compilation error (recursion)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Could someone ease my struggling, please. I am trying to organize two classes (Points) to return opposite class in their methods. Cartesian point class has method that returns Polar point and vice versa.

**Point2D.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "PointPolar2D.h"
class Point2D
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    Point2D(double x, double y);

    PointPolar2D toPolar();

    ~Point2D();
};
```

**Point2D.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Point2D.h"
#include "PointPolar2D.h"


Point2D::Point2D(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y)
{
}

PointPolar2D Point2D::toPolar()
{
    return PointPolar2D(1, 4);
}

Point2D::~Point2D()
{
}
```

**PointPolar2D.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Point2D.h"

class PointPolar2D
{
private:
    double radius;
    double angle;

public:
    PointPolar2D(double radius, double angle);

    Point2D toCartesian();

    ~PointPolar2D();
};
```

**PointPolar2D.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "Point2D.h"

class PointPolar2D
{
private:
    double radius;
    double angle;

public:
    PointPolar2D(double radius, double angle);

    Point2D toCartesian();

    ~PointPolar2D();
};
```

It does not compile. The error says: **toPolar:unknown override specifier** and also **unexpected token(s)preceding ;**

Please, help me figure out the reason. It must be something obvious or not.
I will provide any clarifications if needed.
Thanks.

**EDITED**
Created MCVE, as @Amit proposed. Thanks.

Comment: You might be having an issue with recursive includes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/396084/951890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the names of the classes, I'm guessing that `PointPolar2D` is a sub-class of `Point2D`.

Hence, PointPolar2D.h needs to `#include` Point2D.h. You also have:

```
#include "PointPolar2D.h"
```

in Point2D.h. That is circular inclusion. It leads to all kinds of problems.

Remove that line from Point2D.h and add a forward declaration.

```
class PointPolar2D;
```

You don't need the complete class definition to declare the function.

```
PointPolar2D toPolar();
```

A forward declaration would suffice.

Make sure to `#include` PointPolar2D.h in Point2D.cpp. You need the definition of `PointPolar2D` to implement `Point2D::toPolar`.

Comment: @R Even without all the classes provided you solved this issue. Thanks for your time. +1