# no matching constructor initialization issue in passing pointer to object

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue with passing object pointer in parameter.(it's compiler error)
I have a 2 class, for simplicity I created class one and class two.

one.h

```
#pragma once
#include "two.h"
class one
{
private:
    two* t;
public:
    one();
};
```

one.cpp

```
#include "one.h"
one::one()
{ t = new two(this);//error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'two' }
```

two.h

```
#pragma once
#include "one.h"
class two
{
public:
    explicit two(one*);

};
```

two.cpp

```
#include "two.h"
two::two(one*o)
{ }
```

Comment: Why are you designing it this way?

Comment: Which came first, the chicken or the egg? Both of your header files want each other to be included first. That's not going to work, without forward declarations.

Comment: my actual purpose is run another class member function in the member function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was the egg. If we accept that the designation "chicken" begins with a specific genome (and lasts through a successive period of mutations that did not further substantially affect the physiology of the creature, to the present day), then since genome modifications in this sense happen during reproduction (and not to a mature animal) the "new" genome must first have arisen inside an egg. So not a great analogy ;)

Comment: But which chicken laid the first egg?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No chicken. The parent of the first chicken egg was a not-chicken, by definition.

Comment: (Although it is remotely possible for a random mutation to have arisen during life and been passed down to offspring, _and_ for this scenario to have coincided with the first instance of what we call "chicken", this is highly unlikely. And even if it did happen it is not usual to change the species designation of a living animal when its DNA has been mutated during life)

Comment: My hat is off to @daniel for a great MCVE of a first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.h` files, add forward declarations for the other classes. When you have headers including each other, one will not actually get the include, otherwise they'd expand to include each other infinitely.

So in `one.h` you'll have:

```
#pragma once

class two;  // removed include, added forward declaration

class one
{
private:
    two* t;
public:
    one();
};
```

Then actually do the include in `one.cpp` where you need the complete definition of two

```
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h" // added this include
one::one()
{ t = new two(this);}
```

Comment: It worked but I didn't get yet. why is that happening even if I add pragma once.

Comment: now I got it  from this stackoverflow question - [Headers Including Each Other in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/396094/11216780)

Answer (score 0):

you'd better not include two headers in each other,

you can change the `#include "one.h"` in two.h to a definition like `class one;`.

include two headers in each other, will confuse the compiler, and make many strange errors.

`#include` means extend the full header file in there.

and `#pragma once` make the header file extend only once, you can try to copy the full content of the one.h to where `#include "one.h"` is, and you will find the problem.

for example, in one.cpp, after extend the header file, the file is like this:

```
class two
{
public:
    explicit two(one*);

};
class one
{
private:
    two* t;
public:
    one();
};
one::one()
{
    t = new two(this);
}
```

because there is no declaration or definition of class one before class two, the constructor of class two is not correctly declared, so the error happens.

Comment: The compiler won't be confused (and the errors will be completely logical); it is the programmer who will be confused!

Comment: #include means extend the full header file in there.and #pragma once make the header file extend only once, you can try to copy the full content of the one.h to where #include "one.h" is, and you will find the problem.