# How to handle complex header recursion with variants and using

Tags: c++, recursion, header, c++17

I have (abstractly) 3 headers, two of them containing single variants that calls the other from other. Main structure of those are like:

AB.hpp

```
#ifndef AB
#define AB

//#include "CD.hpp"

namespace HELLO {
    struct A;
    struct B;

    struct A{/*...*/};
    struct B{
        std::stack<CD_var> s;

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, B const &b){
            os << s.top();
            /*more code..*/
            return os;
        }
    };

    using AB_var = std::variant<A, B>;

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, AB_var const &v) {
        switch(v.index()){
            case 0: // A
                os << std::get<A>(v);
                break;
            case 1: // B
                os << std::get<B>(v);
                break;
            default:
                throw std::bad_variant_access();
        }
        return os;
    }
}

#endif
```

CD.hpp

```
#ifndef CD
#define CD

//#include "AB.hpp"

namespace HELLO {
    struct C;
    struct D;

    using CD_var = std::variant<C, D>;
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CD_var const &v);

    struct C{
        std::stack<AB_var> s;
        std::stack<CD_var> t;

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, C const &c){
            os << s.top();
            os << t.top();
            /*more code..*/
            return os;
        }
    }

    struct D{/*...*/}

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CD_var const &v) {
        switch(v.index()){
            case 0: // C
                os << std::get<C>(v);
                break;
            case 1: // D
                os << std::get<D>(v);
                break;
            default:
                throw std::bad_variant_access();
        }
        return os;
    }
}

#endif
```

ABCD.hpp uses both elements in AB.hpp and CD.hpp.

Now the problem is, after thinking about this for hours, I couldn't find a way to link these headers properly. No matter how I link them, it returns an error with tons of error messages due to this. I'd like to separate `AB` and `CD` since they have different functionalities. Please give me a way to make this code work. Thanks.

Comment: Should it be header-only?

Comment: @Evg Does it change the problem? The structure is like (AB CD) -> (ABCD) -> main.cpp

Comment: It can simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to split your headers to .hpp & .cpp files, declarations belong to .hpp files and implementations belong to .cpp files, and in this point, in AB.hpp include CD.h, and in CD.**cpp** include AB.hpp. This should do the work.

EDIT: you also have to use forward declaration in CD.hpp file to use AB_variant.

Something like this:

AB.hpp

```
#ifndef PROJECT_AB_H
#define PROJECT_AB_H

#include "CD.h"

namespace HELLO {
    struct A;
    struct B;

    struct A {/*...*/};

    struct B {
        std::stack<CD_var> s;

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, B const &b);
    };

    using AB_var = std::variant<A, B>;

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, AB_var const &v);
}
#endif
```

AB.cpp

```
#include "AB.h"

namespace HELLO {

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, AB_var const &v) {/*...*/}

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, B const &b) {
        //The right using is: b.s.top();
        /*more code..*/
        return os;
    }
}
```

CD.hpp

```
#ifndef PROJECT_CD_H
#define PROJECT_CD_H

namespace HELLO {
    struct A;
    struct B;
    using AB_var = std::variant<A, B>;

    struct C;
    struct D;

    using CD_var = std::variant<C, D>;

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CD_var const &v);

    struct C {
        std::stack<AB_var> s;
        std::stack<CD_var> t;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, C const &c);
    };

    struct D {/*...*/};
    /*...*/
}

#endif
```

CD.cpp

```
#include "CD.h"
#include "AB.h"

namespace HELLO {

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CD_var const &v) {/*...*/}

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, C const &c) {
        //The right using is: c.s.top();
        //The right using is: c.t.top();
        /*more code..*/
        return os;
    }
}
```

For more info about the compilation time: [Headers Including Each Other in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c)

Comment: This gives an error "Type redefinition with different types". The error is coming from forward declaring AB_var as a class.

Comment: @user5876164 strange, it didn't happen to me. Try the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to split headers into forward declarations and implementations:

```cpp
// AB_forward.hpp

#pragma once
#include <ostream>
#include <variant>

struct A;
struct B;

using AB_var = std::variant<A, B>;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, AB_var const &);

// CD_forward.hpp

#pragma once
#include <ostream>
#include <variant>

struct C;
struct D;

using CD_var = std::variant<C, D>;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, CD_var const &);

// AB.hpp

#pragma once
#include "AB_forward.hpp"
#include "CD_forward.hpp"
#include <stack>

struct A { /*...*/ };
struct B { 
    std::stack<CD_var> s; 
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, B const &);
};

// CD.hpp

#pragma once
#include "AB_forward.hpp"
#include "CD_forward.hpp"
#include <stack>

struct C { 
    std::stack<AB_var> s; std::stack<CD_var> t; 
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, C const &);
};
struct D { /*...*/ };

// AB_CD.hpp   <- implementations are here

#include "AB.hpp"
#include "CD.hpp"

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, B const &) { /* ... */ }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, AB_var const &) { /* ... */ }

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, C const &) { /* ... */ }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, CD_var const &) { /* ... */ }

// main.cpp

#include "AB_CD.hpp"

/* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks for the guideline! The only thing is that the other answer looks more ordered..

Comment: @user5876164, there are many ways to distribute code among headers. After you get the idea, you'll be able to do it the way you prefer. I do not like repeating forward declarations (e.g., `struct A; struct B;` in both `AB.hpp` and `CD.hpp`) and prefer to put them into a single file. Suppose you had 10 structs, would you repeat their declarations 10 times in ten 10 (5) `.hpp` files?.. And suppose you want to change `AB_var` to something else. Then you'll have to edit multiple files. As a general rule, repetitions should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @Evg usually it's one class per file, so in case you have lots of classes, you will add one more file per class (3 files for each class). Both ways have pros and cons in different projects' structures. Personally I prefer forward declaration over more file (especially in large projects).

Comment: @KorelK, all forward declarations can be put into a single file.

Comment: @Ewg so you are using FD, but instead of putting them inside the .hpp file, you choose to seperate them to different file. The only case that I agree with you, is only if you have more than two recursive headers. Because in mine answer, you only use FD in a single time, and in your solution you are using it twice. For this case, and for the usually case, in my opinion my offer is simpler. Fix me if I'm wrong, I think it's an interesting discussion :)

Comment: I am really wondering what is the most convenient way to solve a case like that.

Comment: @KorelK, in your solution you repeat forward declarations twice. This is what I don't like. It can be the case that you need forward declaration of `A` in many other headers like `CD.hpp`, in which you can't include its definition. Will you repeat FDs over and over again? Later, you might want to modify `A` (which can be a complicated template), and you'll have to modify all forward declarations in all headers. (1/2)

Comment: @KorelK, another thing that looks strange to me is the asymmetry between `AB.hpp` and `CD.hpp`. I don't understand why `AB.hpp` includes `CD.hpp`, but `CD.hpp` doesn’t include `AB.hpp`. To understand that, I have to analyze the headers. Suppose I want to create new `EF.hpp`. Should I use `AB.hpp` as a template? Or `CD.hpp`? (2/2) (Your answer was downvoted, and it was not my downvote.)

Comment: @Evg I do agree with you that your way is more generic and flexible than mine, but still does it necessary  to make more complex files in the usually case? As the opener said, he took my offer because it looked simpler to him. Create new files, and change project architecture all because two recursive headers might be a lot of work, for a few gain.

Comment: @KorelK, I do not think that my solution is much more complex, but to me it is much clearer and easier to understand even in this simple case, and this factor outweighs possible complexity. I like symmetry and consistency, they pay for themselves. When I write my answers I try to be more generic and try to demonstrate the general idea in case someone else with a similar but not exactly the same problem finds this question.

Comment: @Evg My answer is the way I handled this problem in every project I went through until now. So I do think it will help to a lot of programmers who will come across this issue. But don't misunderstand me, I do think it's good and important that you wrote this answer, for the cases when my answer won't be enough. BTW you got plus from me ;)

Comment: @KorelK, consensus. :)