# why i can't mutually include c++ classes

Tags: c++

having 2 header files:

```
header1.h
#pragma once
#include "header2.h"
class A
{
  public:
   B b;
};

header2.h
#pragma once
#include "header1.h"
class B
{
  public:
   A a;
};
```

running such code in visual studio gives several error like 'B' unknown override specifier. Why is it that including the two classes mutually in each other gives error?

Comment: Do you know what #include does?

Comment: sorry for the post as it has been already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c